# Number of distinct chess positions and games

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

I was wondering how many total possible chess games/positions are there? I know Shannon calculated an upper bound of about $10^{120}$ legal chess games and $10^{43}$ legal chess positions. Have there been any more recent developments?

Also, will we ever be able to know exactly how many legal chess games/positions are there in total? It will require tons of computing power but by Moore's Law we should eventually have the necessary computing power. Based on current estimates, when will this happen?

Comment: There are 3 chess rules not to overlook: The 3-fold repetition rule, the 50-move rule, and the Insufficient Material Rule. If the pieces still in play are insufficient for either player to checkmate ( no matter what moves are played) then the game is drawn. If 50 consecutive moves by one player, and 49 replies to them, with no pawn moves (of any kind) and no captures (of anything by anything) the game is drawn. If the same  position occurs a third time, with the same player to move and the same moves possible for that player, the game is drawn.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet that's interesting...

Comment: `parsum(x=2,32,binomial(64,x)*binomial(30,x-2)*x!)
%7=1168233055134793149160367203546386400298494927579486272` should be a bound on the number of positions regardless of legality.

Comment: To solve chess, we "only" need to mark the legal positions , we do not need the complete tree although this as mentioned is also finite because of the 50 move rule (the other rules are not necessaty to guarantee a finite game, but they can accelerate the automatic draw).

Comment: It is incredible that Moore's law still holds since the computational power surely is limited in principle. But what we can do with determining whether a position is won, lost or draw , can we also do with determining whether a position is legal. I am convinced that chess will "soon" be solved , but I cannot say that I am happy about this.

Answer (score -2):

To answer the second part of your question, the number of total possible chess positions will eventually be calculated, but the number of chess games is still unimaginably large. [THIS - broken link](https://www.chess.com/chessopedia/view/mathematics-and-chess) site will have a slice of the answers:

> The number of possible chess positions after White’s first ply move is 20 (16 pawn moves and 4 knight moves).  There are 400 possible chess positions after two ply moves (first ply move for White followed by first ply move for Black).

this is because there are $20$ moves for white's move 1, and $20^2$, or $400$ moves at the beginning of move 2. then, the number balloons. the least number of moves to checkmate is 3, called the [fool's checkmate](https://www.chess.com/blog/ChessNetwork/the-shortest-checkmate-in-chess-the-fools-mate). as for the other numbers, look on the site! as for when the numbers will be calculated, i'm not sure---yet.

Comment: The first link is dead, but [OEIS A048987](https://oeis.org/A048987) is this sequence.

Comment: Yes, the number of games is far larger than the number of atoms in the observable universe , but we need it neither to solve chess nor to count the number of legal positions.

Answer (score -2):

We will never know the number exactly, since deciding whether a given Chess position is legal can be incredibly tricky, and an entire area of study, so called "retrograde analysis" is devoted to this.

In this respect, Chess differs from other games like Go, whether determining legality of a position is straightforward, and where the exact number of legal positions has in fact been computed (https://tromp.github.io/go/legal.html).

Recent research has however allowed the number of legal chess positions to be accurately estimated at about 4.8x10^44.
See https://tromp.github.io/go/legal.html for details.

The number of legal games will be vastly larger, but I doubt that even the exponent can be estimated with any accuracy.

Comment: Determining all legal positions is not more difficult than solving chess. It is only a matter of time until chess is solved - unfortunately. Of course, the number of legal positions is huge , but not completely out of reach.